# Discrete mathematics

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Can anyone solve it and explain how?
For the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7\}$, let two numbers be $≈$-equivalent if they have the
same number of factors of $2$. List all the equivalence classes.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you having trouble counting the "number of factors of $2$" in any of those numbers?  It's hard to guess where you are having difficulty.

Comment: $2,\; 6=2\cdot 3\;$ each have **one** factor of $2$. Note that  $4 = 2\cdot 2$ has two factors of $2$.  The rest (all odd, by definition, have no factor of $2$.

Answer (score 2):

What you mean is the $2$-adic valuation. This is the exponent of the power $2^k$ in the prime factorization (If $2$ is no prime factor, the exponent is $0$). Hence, the classes are : The odd numbers (here $1,3,5,7$) with exponent $0$, the single-even numbers (here $2,6$) with exponent $1$ , the double-even numbers (here $4$) with exponent $2$ and so on. Here, you do not have further classes, so the classes are $(1,3,5,7)$ , $(2,6)$ and $(4)$